# Jquery: how to correctly use .next() method?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="demoC12" class="collapse in" style="height: auto;">
    <form id="fd12">
        <input type="button" id="TestButton">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="div" style="margin-top:10px"></div>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hover TableDog mgtb20">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody class="ClassTbody">

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To clear the html in `tbody.ClassTbody` I use the following code:

```
$("body").on("click", "#TestButton", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next("tbody.ClassTbody").html('');
});
```

but it does not work...

Also I need to change the clear html to only the for first element found of `tbody.ClassTbody`.

Tell me please where is the error? How can I correct it?

Comment: Why can't you directly set tbody.classTbody html to ''?

Comment: @malkam becouse question **how right use next()?**

Comment: next() in this case will move you to div id="div" - you never get to the table

Comment: @JayBlanchard in cycle I have several of these same elements on the page, so you need a next().

Comment: @JasonP has provided the answer that will work for you. I don't think that you understand the basics of the next() method and what it is intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next()` can never select anything more than the following sibling.

I would think you could just do this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#TestButton", function(){
    $("tbody.ClassTbody").html('');
});
```

But if you *need* to traverse, try this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#TestButton", function(){
    $(this).closest('div').nextAll('.table').first().find("tbody.ClassTbody").html('');
});
```

Check the documentation for the list of tree traversal methods, and find the ones that will work for you: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: @DylanCorriveau see name question please.

Comment: @learner Was that comment directed toward me? If so, `.next()` is not the function you want here. `.next()` will only select the immediately following sibling. If you specify a selector, it will only return that sibling if the selector matches. There is no way you can start with `#demoC12`, call `.next()`, and end up with `tbody.ClassTbody`.

Comment: @learner It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YxFuW/. Any errors in your javascript console?